# Does the existence of infinite number of Leinster groups indicate the existence of infinite number of perfect numbers?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, perfect-numbers

A Leinster group is a finite group $G$, such, that that the sum of orders of its normal subgroups is $2|G|$. A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper positive divisors.

Tom Leinster proved that an abelian group $G$ is a Leinster group iff it is cyclic and $|G|$ is a perfect number.

There are two conjectures about those objects:

1) "The number of perfect numbers is infinite." (IPN)

2) "The number of Leinster groups is infinite." (ILG)

Obviously, IPN implies ILG, but does ILG imply IPN, or are those two conjectures not equivalent?

Comment: Well if what you say is true the answer is obviously yes : infinitely many (isomorphism classes of) Leinster groups would yield infinitely many perfect numbers

Comment: that's what im tring to prove and its not that obvious, after all im tring to prove that infinite leinster groups indicate there are infinite abelian leinster groups...

Comment: @Max - if you think you have a prove please post it, i will probably except any correct explanation

Comment: i asked the same questions at math over flow

Comment: I had misread the statement you said had been proved

Comment: OK...no problem